# Emerald missing close, maximize and minimize buttons when restoring window from maximized state

Tags: 13.10, compiz, themes, emerald

Emerald is working fine. But when I restore a window which was maximized; the close, maximize and minimize buttons are invisible. The buttons are there and working like if i move the cursor where the button suppose to be the drop down menu comes with the descriptions like `close` etc. But when an application is launching directly to non-maximized state then the buttons are visible. I'm attaching a screenshot here:[image: problem described with picture]

By the way, using Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit. My hardware is: i5 CPU and 8 GB RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not a proper answer. It's an unknown bug (which will not be fixed) Try a different theme. Try to compile emerald again from a different source. This happens only with Ubuntu. It is not to be seen in my Arch Linux box (I'm using the same theme as you with minor modifications). May be Compiz is responsible for this.
[image]

Comment: OK then. Actually I was thinking to put emerald on my custom OS...